# string producer/consumer in C++: std::deque<char> or std::stringstream?

Tags: c++, performance, stream, queue, standard-library

In our application we have a class that produces characters, and another that consumes them. The current implementation dynamically allocates characters as they are produced (using `new`) and delete them (with `delete`) as they are consumed. This is all terribly slow, and I am looking at ways to replace that implementation to improve its performance.

The semantic I need is that of the standard class `queue`: push at the front, pop at the back. The default implementation uses a `deque` IIRC. `deque` is typically implemented using "blocks" or "chunks" of memory, so I expect far less calls to the OS memory allocator, and a significant speed-up, with little additional memory usage.

However, since the data queued is characters (possibly wide characters), an alternative would be to use the standard input/output stream class, namely the character stream `stringstream`. AFAIK, their behaviour is queue-like too.

Is there a better choice a priori? Would both classes have similar allocation patterns? I can try and measure performance of both, but perhaps it doesn't really matter and either would be good enough. In that case, which would be easiest/safest to use?

A secondary matter is concurrency between the producer and the consumer. I can restrict access to be sequential (on the same thread), but a thread-safe implementation is likely to be beneficial performance-wise with current multi-core hardware.

Thanks for your wisdom before I dive in and start coding.

Comment: I'd probably go with `std::deque`, given that it's designed specifically to handle this kind of case. The other possibility would be a fixed-size queue that simply blocks when it's full. With appropriate sizing, blocking is often actually desirable (if one side gets too far behind, blocking can give it more CPU time so it gets a chance to catch up).

Comment: The contiguous memory requirement of a std::deque could affect performance with some large reallocs of the consumer is not fast enough. Although trying it is probably the best answer

Comment: I don't think `std::deque` has a contiguous memory requirement. In fact, Josuttis states the opposite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::stringstream` isn't a queue, since reading characters doesn't consume them. You can simply `seekg(0)` and read the same characeters all over again. Thus, the more you write, the more memory you will consume.

Stick with `std::queue`. The default choice of `std::deque` as the underlying implementation is almost certainly the right one.

Regarding concurrency, it is categorically unsafe to write to `std::queue` while any other thread is reading or writing to it. If you want an efficient blocking queue implementation, you'll have to write or borrow one specifically built for the purpose.

Comment: std::deque has no requirement to release memory to the OS even if it is empty - this could be a consideration for the OP

Comment: @AdrianCornish: Good point. It's difficult to imagine a sane implementation that doesn't release or reuse blocks that fall off either end of the chain. But that's not the same as a guarantee, of course. In C++11, I suppose one could make judicious use of [`std::deque::shrink_to_fit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque/shrink_to_fit).

Comment: @MarceloCanton - Cool - did not know that existed - thank you. While I have the new standard - reading it from start to end hasn't happened yet ;-)

Comment: Since `std::stringstream` doesn't "consume" read characters, I can only use if everything fits in memory. That's not totally out of question, but I need to preflight that

Answer (score 1):

I read this many years ago (I think, did not read it again) when they actually used to send me the magazine before they started asking for silly money for it before they went bust :-).

This might help

http://www.drdobbs.com/parallel/lock-free-queues/208801974

As a side note I work on real time systems processing financial data - and we use fixed length queues generally and throw away data that will not fit in the queue if the consumer cannot processes it - old data is worse than missed data. Of course your requirement may differ.

Comment: And just as a note to this: If you're going to use a fixed length queue, you'd usually implement that as a circular buffer.

Comment: Actually we use SystemV IPC queues - but circular is better, if you can stop the Producer from overwriting data the Consumer is currently reading.

Comment: I read that article, and the followups by Herb Sutter. TL;DR: it's hard! At least as a first step, I will forego threading...