# How to release stringstream resources?

Tags: c++, string, memory-management, stream, stringstream

I have two threads. One writes data into a stringstream, the other reads data from it.

After some trial and error, I figured out that this approach "eats" my memory as the underlaying string seems to grow infinitely (until std::bad_alloc).

After reading from a stringstream, how do I release that part of the underlaying string that is no longer in use? I figured out that

```
myStringStream.str (std::string ());
myStringStream.clear ();
```

frees the string. But this also erases the data that has not been read so far.

Should I just create a new string from time to time and copy the (not yet used) data? Or is a stringstream a dumb approach anyway?

**Edit:**

Thanks for mentioning alternatives. I actually know queues and ringbuffers. I am however not very experienced on when to choose them over another solution. But as it stands: you would not choose a stream approach, would you?

Comment: Is it mandatory to use a stream to communicate between threads? The standard approach would be to use a queue and have the producer thread write strings (or whatever is needed) into the queue and the consumer read from the queue.

Comment: I use the stringstream to parse the data afterwards. What I could do was transporting the data via queue, then create a stringstream from the (queued) data and parse them. The downside is, that the data has not always the same length. Therefore I decided to use a semaphore to signal the reading thread that it can perform it's job.

Comment: Using a queue will simplify things for you, if data is streamed in packets. Otherwise this demonstrates a circular buffer solution for your use case: http://elonen.iki.fi/code/misc-notes/ringbuffer/

Comment: Looks like [duplicate][1]. You shouldn't use strstream when you need queue.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12700563/string-producer-consumer-in-c-stddequechar-or-stdstringstream